# socket io on connection not firing

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) and it doesn't seem like it's connected... I tried with my client application and with [socketio-client-tool](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/), but I'm not getting any connections. here's my code:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

require('./socket/socket')(server);
module.exports = server.listen(4000, () => logger.info(`Listening on port 4000`));
```

**socket.js**

```
module.exports = function (server) {
    const _io = io(server);

    const redisConnection = redisAdapter({ host: 'localHost', port: 6379 });
    logger.info('connected to redis');

    _io.adapter(redisConnection);
    logger.info(`connected to socket.io`);

    _io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('a user connected');
    });
};
```

I'm using ngrok to access the backend. Not sure if that has to do...

Comment: i see a typo with `localHost`. is that relevant somehow?

Comment: @kenmistry Great catch! I changed it, but still getting the same results. It's weird because ngrok is seeing the connection https://prnt.sc/vwp54u but i'm not getting any loggs